# Dividir un array según secuencia

Tags: php, array, split

Básicamente necesito hacer un split a un array cada vez que encuentre una secuencia de 8 ceros seguidos:

**vector base**

```
$vector = [1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
```

El código que modifiqué para realizar la búsqueda de las secuencias de 8 seguidos es:

```
function BuscarEnVector($vectorBuscar, $vector) 
{
    $listaIndices = array_keys($vector, $vectorBuscar[0]);
    $ret = [];
    
    foreach ($listaIndices as $indice) 
    {
        $adicionar = true;
        $resultado = [];
        
        foreach ($vectorBuscar as $i => $valor) 
        {
            if (!(isset($vector[$indice + $i]) && $vector[$indice + $i] == $valor)) 
            {
                $adicionar = false;
                break;
            }
            
            $resultado[] = $indice + $i;
        }
        
        if ($adicionar == true) 
        { 
            $ret[] = $resultado;
        }            
    }
    
    return $ret;
}
```

Uso

```
$vectorCoincidencias = BuscarEnVector([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], $vector);
```

Resultado obtenido:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 5
            [3] => 6
            [4] => 7
            [5] => 8
            [6] => 9
            [7] => 10
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 14
            [1] => 15
            [2] => 16
            [3] => 17
            [4] => 18
            [5] => 19
            [6] => 20
            [7] => 21
        )

)
```

Resultado esperado:

> del indice 0 al 2 no hay ceros seguidos
>
> del indice 3 al 10 hay 8 ceros seguidos
>
> del indice 11 al 13 no hay ceros seguidos
>
> del indice 14 al 21 hay 8 ceros seguidos

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 5
            [3] => 6
            [4] => 7
            [5] => 8
            [6] => 9
            [7] => 10
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11
            [1] => 12
            [2] => 13
        )        
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 14
            [1] => 15
            [2] => 16
            [3] => 17
            [4] => 18
            [5] => 19
            [6] => 20
            [7] => 21
        )
)
```

Que debo modificar para tener el resultado esperado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí dejo una posibilidad. Consiste en una función a la que le pasas un array que se utilizará como separador (`$needle`) y el array que quieres separar (`$array`), entonces se ejecuta el siguiente algoritmo:

1. Convertir los arrays a cadenas de texto
2. Añadir separadores delante y detrás de la cadena buscada (p.e. usando [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)).
3. Romper la cadena por los separadores (p.e.: usando [`preg_split`](http://php.net/preg_split) que te permite eliminar los elementos vacíos que quedarían si la cadena buscada está al principio y/o al final).
4. Romper los elementos internos del array en array individuales (p.e. usando [`str_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)).
5. Devolver el array generado.

Aquí dejo un ejemplo del código:

```
function separarVector($needle, $array){

    // convertimos los dos arrays en cadenas de texto
    $needle2 = implode("",$needle);
    $array2  = implode("", $array);

    // usamos expresiones regulares para añadir comas delante y detrás de la cadena buscada
    $array2  = preg_replace("/" . $needle2 . "/", "," . $needle2 . ",", $array2);

    // usamos expresiones regulares para convertirlo en un array
    $array2  = preg_split("/,/", $array2, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

    // separa las cadenas internas en arrays
    for($x = 0; $x < count($array2); $x++) {
        $array2[$x] = str_split($array2[$x]);
    }

    // devuelve el array de arrays
    return $array2;

}

$vector  = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
$vector2 = separarVector([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], $vector);
print_r($vector2);

$vector  = [1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
$vector2 = separarVector([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], $vector);
print_r($vector2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Esta función te devuelve el resultado que esperas:

```
function splitVector($param, $array){

  $total = count($param);
  $atotal = count($array);
  $i = 0;
  $k = 0;
  $output = array();
  while($i < $atotal){
      if(!isset($output[$k])) $output[$k] = array();
      if ($param ==  array_slice($array,$i,$total)){
          $k++;
          for($o = 0; $o < $total; $o++){
              $output[$k][] = $i;
              $i++;
          }
          $k++;
      }else{
          $output[$k][]  = $i;    
          $i++;
      }
  }
  return $output;
}

$vector = [1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
$vectores = splitVector([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], $vector);
```

Answer (score 0):

He creado esta función que devuelve el resultado que esperas, dime si te soluciona el problema:

```
function SplitAfter($param, $array){

    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        $string .= $value.',';
    }

    $string = substr($string, 0, -1);

    $output = preg_split( '/('.$param.')/' , $string , -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE|PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY );


    foreach($output as $key => $value){
        $output[$key] = preg_split( '/,/' , $value , -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY );
    }

    return $output;

}

$vector = [1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
$vectores = SplitAfter(',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0', $vector);
```

Comment: ¿Qué pasa si los 8 ceros seguidos están al principio?

Comment: @webly, el primer parámetro de la función es un string, no es un vector, por lo tanto tu solución no es correcta. De todos modos muchas gracias.